# Which mobile EOS wallets lets you create an account by providing your public key?

Tags: wallet, public-key, android, mobile, ios

Is there an Android or iOS EOS wallet that lets you create an EOS account by using your own generated public key?

Comment: Although not an iOS or Android solution, you can checkout https://3rdex.com/account/create for creating your EOS account in a web interface by providing your own public keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only your public key for your wallet will block most of the functionality of EOS, as being said Eoslynx is the best for only using public key, if you are afraid to use your private key you should learn about separating public and master key.

Answer (score 1):

Eoslynx can do that for you but you have to pay some money to create an account as they have to allocate resources for your account.